# Beginner in C Programming

Tags: c

Can you help me with my code, there seems to be an error.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    int apples = 0;
    int dozenofApples;
    int extraApples;
    int totalPrice;
    char response;
   

    printf("Input amount apples: ");
    scanf("%d", &apples);
   
    dozenofApples = apples / 12;
    extraApples = apples % 12;
   
    printf("You have %d dozen apples ", dozenofApples);

    if (extraApples <= 1) {
        printf("and %d extra apples", extraApples);
       
    } else {
        printf("and %d extra apples", extraApples);
       
    }
    if (dozenofApples >= 2) {
        printf(" and this will cost you 120 PHP per dozen.");
       
    } else {
        printf(" and this will cost you 150 PHP per dozen.");
    }
   
    printf("\nContinue to purchase? Yes/No\n");
    scanf("%s", &response);
   
    if (response == 'Yes') {
        printf("Purchase Complete! Come again!");
    } else if (response == 'No') {
        printf("Purchase cancelled.");
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
    }
       
        return 0;
}
```

I want the response char set with the input Yes or No, and using the if else statement it outputs the result when the purchase is complete or not.

Comment: `if (response == 'Yes')` is incorrect for several reasons. a) `scanf("%s", &response);` requires a an array buffer, not a single character, b) you cannot compare strings in C with `==` use `strcmp` and c) you should be using `"Yes"` not `'Yes'`.

Comment: The errors in your code show: 1. You need a better IDE, what IDE are you using? 2. You have misunderstanding of conversion specifier of `printf`, what textbook are you using to learn C? 3. You misunderstood C-string and char, still, what textbook are you using?

Comment: C is not a language that you can learn by trial and error. You need to learn the language before you can use it. [Here's a list of books to help you get started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write a `char` literal with single quotes like `'a'` and `char`s are for single characters, not for whole strings (multiple letters). To use a string you would need double quotes like `"Hello, World!"`. Your `'Yes'` and `'No'` are ill formed. However you can not compare strings with the equality operator (`==`), you will need [`strcmp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp).

The following example shows how you could compare two strings as you would like to do in your code. Note that I used [`fgets()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) for user input instead of [`scanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) as you did.

```
#include <stdio.h>   // fgets(), fprintf(), printf(), stdin, stderr
#include <stdlib.h>  // EXIT_FAILURE (1), EXIT_SUCCESS (0)
#include <string.h>  // strcmp()

int main() {
    // enough storage for "Yes" with the terminating NUL ('\0')
    char response[4];

    if (fgets(response, sizeof response, stdin) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read input from the console!");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (strcmp("Yes", response) == 0) {
        printf("Purchase Complete! Come again!");
    }
    else if (strcmp("No", response) == 0) {
        printf("Purchase cancelled.");
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid user input!");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```